# Codeigniter no envía correos desde mi servidor host

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un problema tengo una app en CodeIgniter 3.0 y la configure para que envíe un email al registrarse un usuario con datos de confirmación, en localhost me funciona bien, envía bien el email, pero en servidor host no funciona estoy haciendolo con los datos de email gmail.

**¿Alguien me puede asesorar con mi error?**

Estoy usando la librería de CodeIgniter y esta configuración:

```
// Config param
    $configGmail = array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'miemail@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'miclave',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );
```

Comment: Hola Irwing, bienvenido. Deberias añadir tambien el codigo que tienes que envia el email. Un saludo

Comment: Revisa los logs del servidor (especialmente el de errores). Si está fallando la función probablemente se estén registrando los mensajes de error en los logs

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar cambiando algunos parámetros en la configuración con lo que te quedaría algo como esto:

```
$configGmail = array(
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'SMTPAuth'  => true,
    'SMTPSecure'=> 'TLS',
    'smtp_user' => 'miemail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'miclave',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'newline'   => "\r\n"
);
```

A ver si te funciona....

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

gracias amigos, lo he solucionado re-configurando las cosas así:

```
$configGmail = array(
    'useragent'     => 'CodeIgniter',
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mail.irwing.com.ve',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_timeout' => 5,
    'priority' => 3,
    'smtp_user' => 'mi@email.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'miclave',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'crlf'  => "\r\n",
    'newline'   => "\r\n",
    'validate'  => FALSE
);
```