# Enviar un email con CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3, html-correo

hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar  en el correo tengo el mio y mi contraseña pero no me manda ningun error ni en consola ya lo subi a una pagina no lo tengo de manera local no me marca ningún tipo de error solo envía que no se envió el mensaje espero me puedan ayudar ya intente cambiar al puerto 25 y puerto 587 sigue dando en mismo problema
en mi  carpeta config cree un archivo al cual le puse el siguiente Código de email.php

```
 <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';  // protocolo de envio de correo
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.googlemail.com'; // dirección SMTP del servidor                              
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'mi-correo@gmail.com'; // remplazarlo por un cuenta real de Gmail - usuario SMTP
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'mi-password'; 
            $config['smtp_port'] = '465'; // o el '587' --  Puerto SMTP 
            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '6';  // Tiempo de espera SMTP(segundos)
            //$config['email']['newline']  = '\r\n';
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // o text para texto sin HTML
```

en mi controlador

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Email_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__Construct();
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation','email'));
        $this->load->helper(array('url','html'));
       }

function index(){
       
       $data['title'] = 'Formulario de Contacto';
       $data['msg'] = NULL;
     
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Nombre', 'required|alpha|min_length[3]');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Celular', 'required|numeric');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Ciudad y dirección', 'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');  
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Mensaje', 'required');  
     
       $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'el campo %s es requerido');
       $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email', 'El email no es válido');
         
           $this -> form_validation -> set_error_delimiters('<ul><li>', '</li></ul>');
     
       $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'el campo %s es requerido');
       $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email', 'El email no es válido');
         
           $this -> form_validation -> set_error_delimiters('<ul><li>', '</li></ul>');
      
      
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('send_email', $data); 

          
            }else{
                      
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $mobil = $this->input->post('phone');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');
                      
        // Datos para enviar el correo
            $this->email->from('ejemplo@gmail.com', 'Ejemplo');
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject('Email enviado con CI y Gmail');              
            $this->email->message($message);
          
            if($this->email->send()){
          
            $data['title']='Mensaje Enviado';
            $data['msg'] = 'Mensaje enviado a su email';
                     // echo $this->email->print_debugger(); exit;                            
            $this->load->view('send_email', $data);
          
             }else{
                $data['title']='El mensaje no se pudo enviar';
                $this->load->view('send_email', $data);
            
             }
                        
           }
        }
    }
```

en mi vista  send_mail.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>   
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px; color: #444;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;}
       
    #container{
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 20px;
        width:500px;     margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
        padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 2px;} 
      
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-weight: bold;color: #21759b;}
    
    #content{
    width: 790px;padding:5px; min-height:400px;}
    
    #form_email{
        width:500px;
        border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #C8C8C8;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom:20px; padding: 16px;
        width: 420px;
    }
    #error{
        width:400px;
        border: 1px solid #bf0100;
        background-color: #FFEBE8;
        margin: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
    
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div>
        <h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php if(validation_errors()){ ?>
       
        <div id="error"><?php echo validation_errors();?></div>
       
    <?php  } // fin del if que evalua los errores del formulario
    
      $attributes = array('id' => 'form_email');
     
       if($msg===NULL){
         
     echo form_open('email_controller', $attributes);
    
           $name = array('name'=>'name', 'id'=>'name','placeholder'=>'Nombre','value'=>set_value('name'), 'size'=> '35',);
           $phone = array('name'=>'phone', 'id'=>'phone','placeholder'=>'Teléfono','value'=>set_value('phone'), 'size'=> '35',);
           $address = array('name'=>'address','id'=>'address','placeholder'=>'Ciudad y dirección','value'=>set_value('address'), 'size'=> '35',);
           $email = array('name'=>'email', 'id'=>'email','placeholder'=>'Email', 'value'=>set_value('email'), 'size'=> '35',); 
           $message =array('name'=>'message', 'cols'=>'50', 'id'=>'message','placeholder'=>'Mensaje...','value'=>set_value('message'),);
     ?>
          <div><?php echo form_label('Nombre');?></div>
                 
          <div><?php echo form_input($name);?></div>
          <div><?php echo form_label('Teléfono');?></div>  
          <div><?php echo form_input($phone);?></div>
          <div><?php echo form_label('Ciudad y direccción');?></div> 
          <div><?php echo form_input($address);?></div>
          <div><?php echo form_label('Email');?></div>
          <div><?php echo form_input($email);?></div>
          <div><?php echo form_label('Mensaje');?></div>
          <div><?php echo form_textarea($message)?></div>    
    <div>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Enviar');?> 
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?> 
    
     <?php }else
               { echo anchor('email_controller','Enviar otro mensaje').br(2);
           }?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[me guié en este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47980/codeigniter-no-env%C3%ADa-correos-desde-mi-servidor-host) 
[este es el código completo](http://elprogramadorjunior.blogspot.com/2013/09/enviar-un-email-con-codeigniter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Es un criterio personal pero me gusta trabajar con phpMailer en codeigniter. Su implementación es sencilla y funciona muy bien.

1. descargas la libreria de su repositorio en github [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2. luego en en la carpeta `application/third_party` de codeigniter creas una carpeta llamada PHPMailer y copias los archivos que desgarcaste del repositorio que se encuentran en la caperta `PHPMailer/src/`
3. luego en la carpeta `application/libraries` de Codeigniter creas una clase llamada `phpmailer_lib.php` con este codigo.

```
    <?php
    
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
    class Phpmailer_lib{
        public function __construct(){
            log_message('Debug', 'PHPMailer class is loaded.');
        }
    
        public function load(){
            require_once APPPATH.'third_party/PHPMailer/Exception.php';
            require_once APPPATH.'third_party/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
            require_once APPPATH.'third_party/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
    
            $mail=new PHPMailer;
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = "<tu host>";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "<tu email>";
            $mail->Password = "<tu password>";
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->setFrom("<Correo quien envia>", "<Nombre personalizado>");
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Si tu correo contiene codigo HTML
            return $mail;
        }
    }
```

4. en el Controller donde vayas hacer uso del mismo haces una llamada a la libreria en el constructor asi

```
<?php defined("BASEPATH") or exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Email extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("phpmailer_lib");
    }

function email(){
        $mail = $this->phpmailer_lib->load();

        $mail->addAddress("<A quien envias el correo>");
        $mail->Subject = "<Asunto del correo>";
        $mail->Body = "Contenido de tu correo";

       if ($mail->send()) {
            echo "Mensaje enviado";
        } else {
              echo "Mailer Error " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                        
        }

}

}
```

Con este codigo podras reutilizar en cualquier Controlador